# Optimizing the use of foreach

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a small peice of code where for each is being used. I have optimized my code, but my boss expects me to optimize it even further more. I have no idea what further optimization can be done here.

```
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    //When oveeride is false and you have to download all the files
    if (Override.Equals(false)) {
        //putting the matches from regular expression into DownloadFileStruct oject
        df = new DownloadFileStruct(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);

        //Adding DownloadFileStruct object to a array list
        DownloadFileList.Add(df);
    }

    //When override is true and a paticular file has to be downloaded
    else if (match.Groups[2].Value.Equals(OverrideFileName)) {
            //putting the matche from regular expression into a DownloadFileStruct oject
            df = new DownloadFileStruct(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);

            //Adding DownloadFileStruct object to a array list
            DownloadFileList.Add(df);
        }                   
    }               
}
```

What my boss says "You do not need an ‘if’ and an ‘else if’ that execute the same code in both branches".

Comment: This should probably be on [codereview.se]

Comment: Are you really telling us that you can regex match, but not combine two logical statements into one?

Comment: He is not asking for *optimization* in the sense we usually mean (performance improvements), but seems to be suggestion an improvement in the way the code is organized to make it more *maintainable*.

Comment: @nvoigt : Exactly, I did not mean code optimization from a performance point of view, but from t=maintainablility point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify the code to this:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    if (Override && !match.Groups[2].Value.Equals(OverrideFileName))
        continue;

    df = new DownloadFileStruct(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
    DownloadFileList.Add(df);
}
```

Or LINQ-ish:

```
DownloadFileList = 
    matches.Cast<Match>()
           .Where(x => !Override || x.Groups[2].Value.Equals(OverrideFileName))
           .Select(x => new DownloadFileStruct(x.Groups[1].Value,
                                               x.Groups[2].Value))
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use a OR in the if instead of repeating your code twice.

Its not about optimization, its about not having to maintain 2 code branches that do exactly the same thing.

```
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    //When oveeride is false and you have to download all the files
    if (Override.Equals(false) || match.Groups[2].Value.Equals(OverrideFileName)) {
        //putting the matches from regular expression into DownloadFileStruct oject
        df = new DownloadFileStruct(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);

        //Adding DownloadFileStruct object to a array list
        DownloadFileList.Add(df);
    }                     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well it's not really optimization, but your code *would* be simpler as:

```
if (!Override || match.Groups[2].Value == OverrideFileName)
{
    var df = new DownloadFileStruct(match.Groups[1].Value,
                                    match.Groups[2].Value);
    DownloadFileList.Add(df);
}
```

(It's not clear where you're declaring `df`, but it would make sense to declare it *inside* the `if` statement, assuming you're not actually using it elsewhere. Or get rid of it entirely and just use `DownloadFileList.Add(new DownloadFileStruct(...))`.

Comment: actually this df is being used in different functions. Therefor it has to be there

Comment: @user2754845: Is it being used for the same thing in all places? Do you really want the value to be "the last item added to the list"? That sounds very odd to me - in general it's best to limit the scope of each local variable as tightly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 foreach (Match match in matches) {
    //When oveeride is false and you have to download all the files
    //OR
    //When override is true and a paticular file has to be downloaded
    if ((Override.Equals(false)) || (match.Groups[2].Value.Equals(OverrideFileName))) {
        //putting the matches from regular expression into DownloadFileStruct oject
        df = new DownloadFileStruct(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);

        //Adding DownloadFileStruct object to a array list
        DownloadFileList.Add(df);
    }

}
```